# Built-in image lazy loading: Does it come with a polyfill for older browsers?

Tags: images, javascript, media

It's neat that WordPress now automatically adds the `loading="lazy"` attribute to images. My question is: Does WP now also have a built-in JS polyfill for browsers that don't support the `loading` attribute? CanIUse.com reports less than 75% global browser support of the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Browsers that do not support the attribute will just continue loading images like normal, so it wasn't really necessary to include one.

If you want to add one yourself, there are others available that you could include yourself, such as [this one](https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill).